# What is the correct way of sizing a control inside its own WindowProc function?

Tags: c, winapi

I want to adjust the size of a custom control and make it topmost when it is active and has at least one line. Is it safe or even good coding to call `SetWindowPos()` from inside the same control `WindowProc()`? I am working on WinAPI directly.

Comment: It is not.  It should be up to the parent window to arrange window content.  So send a message to it to let it know.

Comment: @HansPassant It is definitively another possible way which involves more coding. Could you please elaborate on why is it not safe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe. Many developers do this to alter the state of their window. For example, developers will call `SetWindowPos()` with the `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` flag during their `WM_CREATE` handler to recalculate the client area of their window.

Calling `SetWindowPos()` with the same window handle of the same control's `WindowProc` is fine, just make sure all handles and flags are valid.

Comment: Thank you, just what I needed to know!